# Copy and paste the web page data into a notepad

Tags: vba, internet-explorer, excel

I need to copy open a XML in IE and select the content(Ctrl+A) in the webpage and copy them (Ctrl+c) and paste them in a notepad. Below is the code but it is not working.

```
Dim ie As Object 
Dim ieDoc As Object 
Dim Data As String

Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application") 
ie.navigate "C:\Data\test_10.xml" ie.Visible = True

Do Until (ie.readyState = 4 And Not ie.Busy)
    DoEvents 
Loop

SendKeys "^a", True 
Application.Wait (5) 
SendKeys "^c" 
Dim FileNo As Integer 
FileNo = FreeFile 
Open "C:\Data\Sample.txt" For Output As FileNo 
SendKeys "^v", True 
Close FileNo
```

Comment: What does it do instead of working ?

Answer (score 1):

The `Open` statement doesn't open a Notepad application, it just creates a file handle for Input / Output to a file from within VBA. You need to create a notepad application object similar to the way you create the IE application object.

Also consider avoiding `SendKeys` all together. Instead

- read out the data from the IE object into a string variable using the `InnerHTML` property
- write out the string into a flat file using `Open` / `Write`
- optionally re-open the text file in the notepad application

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Sub pExtractXMLData()

    Dim strURLtoNavigate        As String
    Dim strHTML                 As String

    strURLtoNavigate = "C:\Data\test_10.xml"
    strHTML = UsingXmlParser(strURLtoNavigate)
    Call WriteVarToDisk(strHTML, "C:\Data\Sample.txt")

End Sub




Public Function UsingXmlParser(strUrl As String)

    Dim objxmlhttp As Object

    Set objxmlhttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    objxmlhttp.Open "GET", strUrl, False
    objxmlhttp.send
    'objxmlhttp.WaitForResponse
    UsingXmlParser = objxmlhttp.ResponseText

    Set objxmlhttp = Nothing

End Function

Public Sub WriteVarToDisk(vartowrite, FiletoWrite)

    On Error Resume Next
    Dim fso, MyFile
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set MyFile = fso.CreateTextFile(FiletoWrite, True)
    MyFile.WriteLine (vartowrite)
    MyFile.Close

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this .. you can open the notepad in excel. do all the works and save back as notepad..

Below codes will help you.

```
Sub ImportXMLtoList()
    Dim strTargetFile As String
    Dim wb as Workbook
   dim dwb as workbook

         Application.Screenupdating = False
         Application.DisplayAlerts = False
         strTargetFile = "C:\Data\test_10.xml"
         Set wb = Workbooks.OpenXML(Filename:=strTargetFile,LoadOption:=xlXmlLoadImportToList)
         Application.DisplayAlerts = True
         wb.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Copy 
        set dwb = workbooks.open("C:\Data\Sample.txt")
            dwb.activesheet.range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues       
            dwb.close true
         wb.Close False
         Application.Screenupdating = True
    End Sub
```